# MERN App - Error when hosting my app on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, api-design

[different response result when I use localhost url or the heroku url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxaPw.png)

As you can see in the picture, in blue we succesfully have the result response. But not when hosted in heroku (green on picture).

Here is the response from api when I try to fetch:
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMGyo.png)

But those params are set in .env file (backend).

Can someone help me with this ? The cors is configured on the backend, so I don't know what I can do more...

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const colors = require("colors");
const dbConnect = require("./database/dbConnect");

dotenv.config();

// *** ROUTES IMPORT ***
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/users-routes");
const ovhRoutes = require("./routes/ovh-routes");
const renewDomainsRoutes = require("./routes/renew-domain-routes");
const meRoutes = require("./routes/me-routes");
const internetBsRoutes = require("./routes/internetbs-routes");
const domainsRoutes = require("./routes/domains-routes");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/order-routes");

// execute database connection
dbConnect();

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

/**
 * ROUTES
 */
app.use("/api/users", usersRoutes); // => /api/users/...
app.use("/api/ovh", ovhRoutes); // => /api/ovh/...
app.use("/api/renew", renewDomainsRoutes);
app.use("/api/me", meRoutes);
app.use("/api/internetbs", internetBsRoutes);
app.use("/api/domains", domainsRoutes);
app.use("/api/order", orderRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  throw new HttpError("Could not find this route.", 404);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(error.code || 500);
  res.json({ message: error.message || "An unknown error occurred!" });
});

/**
 * DEPLOYMENT
 */

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Step 1:
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build")));

  // Step 2:
  app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(
  process.env.PORT || 5000,
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`.blue.bold)
);
```

The data are fetched from internet.bs API.

Thanks all!

Comment: Obviously your cors configuration is incorrect because you are getting a cors error. And as you decided not to reveal any details, nobody will be able to help you

Comment: @derpirscher I've just edited the post with cors configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use `app.use(cors())` and a custom cors handler together. `app.use(cors())` should suffice and enable CORS for all origins.

Comment: And just to be clear: `ita-consult.herokuapp.com` is your own project, right? The code shown above is deployed into that heroku instance?

Comment: Yes it is my own project and it is deployed on that in heroku.

Comment: if `app.use(cors())` doesn't work, there is something else going on on your backend you are not showing us. Maybe the resonse is modifed later on. Maybe you have some other middleware that is already throwing an error and returning to the client before the `cors` middleware has had a chance to add the respective headers. I've used the `cors` middleware in many projects and it's working perfectly fine ...

Comment: I've added the server.js file. I think cors is working fine, because others api calls work correctly.

Comment: So where is the CORS error in your output then coming from? And whats the real problem?

Comment: I think the real problem is that I'm not able to fetch internet.bs API because of the error : "Invalid API KEY and/or Password". It's like it's not getting those infos from my backend. But in local, everything is ok.

Comment: well, then provide an valid api key or password ..

Comment: It's done! But I get a 503 error message and CORS issue.

Comment: But I think there is a problem with this library : https://github.com/oitozero/node-internetbs.